# C++ Read and store variables from two columns in a txt file

Tags: c++, graph, candlestick-chart

I am currently trying to create a candlestick chart representing high and low temperatures for my C++ class. In this assignment, we are provided a txt file with two data columns in the following format:

Average Monthly Low High Temperatures(F)

X Y

X Y

X Y

I have successfully been able to read the txt file, but am confused as how to select specific data. I would like to essentially skip the first sentence and store the remaining variables to create the graph. This is what I am having trouble with.

In the end, I need to display the first line of the text file, as well as display the graph. I would very much like your help.

If there is a more efficient way of doing this, I would love to learn more!

Comment: "*This is what I am having trouble with.*" - why? What is troubling you exactly? Please be more specific. What does your code look like that is not working for you?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Don't be discouraged by negative votes -- your problem is OK to ask here, but the question as it is now isn't terribly well put. In order to help you, we need to know more precisely what you have trouble with. For example, are you at all familiar with input in C++? (If not, you should read some basic tutorials first.) Did you try to code anything yet? If not, the typical answer here is to try that and then come back with a new question about specific problems you have. If you did, by all means show it to us.

Answer (score 1):

You should split the big problem into smaller problems and then solve the smallest problem first. Additionally, you should make use of buildinC++ functionality. An,in C++ you should use an object oriented approach.

That means, store data and their related functions in one object. So, the data and the methods, operating on this data.

I would propose the build 2 classes (or structs). On holds just one pair of low and high temperature.

The second class, holds the header line and a list (implemented as `std::vector`) of low-high-temperature pairs.

The methods that we needin our example are extraction from and insertion into a stream.

For this we usethe well known operators `<<` and `>>` and add them to our class. Here we will do all necessary IO-operations.

So, if we split the big problem into smaller parts according to the above approach, then we will get easier to understand and better readable code.

Last but not least, we will use existing functions from the standard library, like `std::copy`.

The `istream_iterator` and `std::ostream_iterator` will simply call the underlying extratcor operator `>>` and inserter operator `<<`.

An example for a complete program (one of many possible soultions) can be seen below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

// A data struct that can hold a low and a high temperatur and knows, how reaad and write its data
struct LowHighTemperature {

    // The data
    double low{};
    double high{};

    // The extractor operator for reading values from a stream
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, LowHighTemperature& lht) {
        return is >> lht.low >> lht.high;
    }
    // The inserter operator for writing values to a stream
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const LowHighTemperature& lht) {
        return os << lht.low << '\t' << lht.high;
    }
};

// A list with high and low temperatures and a header line
struct TemperatureList {
    // The data
    std::string header{};
    std::vector<LowHighTemperature> lowHighTemperature{};

    // The extractor operator for reading values from a stream
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, TemperatureList& tl) {

        // Delete potentioally pre existing data
        tl.lowHighTemperature.clear();
        // Read the header line
        if (std::getline(is, tl.header))
            // Now read all temperatures
            std::copy(std::istream_iterator<LowHighTemperature>(is), {}, std::back_inserter(tl.lowHighTemperature));
        return is;
    }
    // The inserter operator for writing values to a stream
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const TemperatureList& tl) {
        // Show header
        os << tl.header << '\n';
        // Show temperatures
        std::copy(tl.lowHighTemperature.begin(), tl.lowHighTemperature.end(), std::ostream_iterator<LowHighTemperature>(os, "\n"));
        return os;
    }
};


// Please store the path to your temperatures source file here
const std::string temperatureFileName{ "r:\\temperatures.txt" };

int main() {

    // Open source file and check, if it is open
    if (std::ifstream temperaturFileStream{ temperatureFileName }; temperaturFileStream) {

        // Here we will store the list with all temperatures and the header
        TemperatureList temperatureList{};

        // Read all data from file stream
        temperaturFileStream >> temperatureList;

        // For debug purposes, you show the result on the screen
        std::cout << temperatureList;
    }
    else {
        std::cerr << "\n\nError: Could not open '" << temperatureFileName << "'\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can add whatever other methods you need for you own calculations.

You can access the first temperature pair via `temperatureList.lowHighTemperature[0]`

I hope you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You read a line in C++ with `std::getline()`. Note that it is good practice to check the return value of all input functions in order to detect faulty or missing data or media problems etc. `getline()` as well as the input `operator>>()` return the input stream. Streams have a handy conversion to bool: When an error has been encountered (read error, end of file), the conversion yields `false`; if the stream is OK, it is true. This conversion with these semantics has been designed exactly so that it is convenient to check the success of an input operation:

```
std::string header;
if(!std::getline(infile, header)) { 
    std::cerr << "Couldn't read first line\n"; 
    exit(1); 
}
// keep line for later output. 
// Now read the number pairs. The numbers must be pairs but they actually don't
// have to be on a single line (but it doesn't hurt either).

int a, b;
// The read could fail for other reasons as well; 
// a more robust program would look at the status bits of the stream
// and, if an error occurred, print an error message.
while (infile >> a >> b) { // will be false when EOF is reached
{
    // print your tree or whatever
}
```